# Datatable inline editing without editor plugin

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, datatables, editor

I was using 'editor' plugin for data table and following was the code:

Data table editor defined as:

```
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: '/contact/' + Contact.id,
        table: "#contact-datatable",
        fields: [ {
                    name: "id",
                  }, {
                    name: "category",
                    type: "check",
                    options: [
                              { label: 'Science', value: "Science" },
                              { label: 'Maths', value: 'Maths' },
                              { label: 'Economics', value: 'Economics' },
                             ]
                 }
                    ................
              ]
    });
```

.....

```
$('#contact-datatable').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
                editor.inline( this, { submitOnBlur: true } );
            } );
```

Attaching the page with this: When we click on Category, it shows a dropdown for editing (using editor plugin).

But the problem is datatables' editor plugin is not opensource and my project doesn't allow a payable plugin at all.

Can anyone please help me for inline editing in datatables with out 'editor' plugin?

Following is the code I wrote without editor :

```
Contact.dataTable = $('#contact-datatable').dataTable( {
        "ajax": {
                "url" : '/Contact/list/' + Contact.id,
                "dataSrc": function(check) {
                   check.id = Contact.id;
                   return json.check;
                  },
                },
            "responsive": true,
            "order": [],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id"},
                { "data": "category" },
                { "data": "course" },
                ]
        } );
```

Category and Course will be a dropdown - and this has to be edit inline. Below attached a page example.

I need 'Category' as an inline editor dropdown and then there will be a button to save [image]

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Datatables rock! And SpryMedia let us play with it for free! I'm not 100% sure I've used the Editor Plugin despite buying it but I am pleased that I've contributed to its development in some way. One of the main reasons I've not used the plugin is because I was too skint to afford it for a while so wrote my own versions and that's really not that difficult. The steps are quite simple:

- Detect click on row (you've already done this)
- Get the data from the row (not at all hard)
- Populate a form with that data (probably within a modal)
- Update the server with the new values once the form is submitted
- Update the row once the server has been updated

The plugin makes all that easy and allows you to figure out the backend as well. The steps above aren't all that difficult but I've not come across something that does it all for you except for the Editor Plugin. Work through the steps and you'll get there.

Comment: Could you please help me with some codes - I have used 'rows().data()'  for getting data from row. But not sure how to populate the form  with this. Please help!

Comment: Of course I can, are you getting all of the data from the row that you need? I'm guessing that there is a unique ID within the row as well for sending stuff back to the server? Where is your form going to be? It should be simple enough to work up a JSFiddle with the start of this process. Would you like to do that? Do you only want to edit one field or many?

Comment: I have edited question with my current code. As I am new to this, finding difficulty for continuing for taking data. i would like to edit 2 fields - that is also dropdown in 2 fields.

Comment: Did you look at the JSFiddle?

Comment: Changed it to inline, all of 10 minutes work. How you trigger the change is now up to you. But first 3 stages now completed.

Comment: I am getting error - "TypeError: Contact.dataTable.row is not a function" when I am using 'var data = Contact.DataTable.row(row).data();'

Comment: Did you look at the JSFiddle? I updated it last week.

Comment: I used the fiddle in Chrome but it only transforms the next cell clicked on if you changed the previous cell to another value than it was. If you leave it as it, it won't transform subsequent cells.

Comment: @devc2 that's in interesting issue, if you check the fiddle then events are fired on the `change` event, if you're not changing anything it perhaps might be better to have a cancel button within the cell in order to get things back to the way they were...? Or a group of 2 buttons, one of which saves and the other which cancels any editing? What you decide to do depends upon your use case I gress, perhaps submit you use case as a question rather than add a comment to an existing one?

Comment: @annoyingmouse Your answer is much more an advertisement and too irrelevant being related to the question... Did not you read the question?

Comment: @annoyingmouse Search function will not work on editable data. else everything works fine. please update JSFiddle accordingly.

Comment: If that's a request then your phrasing could be slightly better, it might even be better couched in terms of another question? Done anyway as it was fun.

Comment: @chudasamachirag This is a game that could go on and on: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/zoajso3x/ :-)

Comment: @annoyingmouse Thanks for the code. How can we bind the value in textbox? and Would it be possible to show an update button after editing? Could you please add this to your example?

Comment: @user2768132 you'll have to elaborate I'm afraid — this thread started something like 5 years ago. Perhaps ask a new question, and we'll try to help.

Comment: @annoyingmouse I have created a new question. you can find below. please help,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706289/inline-edit-in-javascript-datatable

Answer (score 10):

I wrote my own code for editing inline and made it such that you can edit complete row and define the columns you want to be editable by user.

here : https://github.com/sinhashubh/datatable-examples

Steps to do this:

1. Handle click even on the clicked row/cell.

   ```
           $("#dtexample tbody").on('click', 'tr td', function (e) {
                   RoweditMode($(this).parent());
               });

           function RoweditMode(rowid) {
               var prevRow;
               var rowIndexVlaue = parseInt(rowid.attr("indexv"));
               if (editIndexTable == -1) {
                   saveRowIntoArray(rowid);
                   rowid.attr("editState", "editState");
                   editIndexTable = rowid.rowIndex;
                   setEditStateValue(rowid, rowIndexVlaue + 2);
               }
               else {
                   prevRow = $("[editState=editState]");
                   prevRow.attr("editState", "");
                   rowid.attr("editState", "editState");
                   editIndexTable = rowIndexVlaue;
                   saveArrayIntoRow(prevRow);
                   saveRowIntoArray(rowid);
                   setEditStateValue(rowid, rowIndexVlaue + 2);
               }
           }
           function saveArrayIntoRow(cureentCells) {
               for (var k in EditRowData) {
                   $($(cureentCells).children('.' + k)[0]).html(EditRowData[k]);
               }
           } 
           function saveRowIntoArray(cureentCells) {
               $.each(ColumnData, function (index, element) {
                   if (element.Editable == true) {
                       var htmlVal = $($(cureentCells).children('.' + element.Name)[0]).html();
                       EditRowData[element.Name] = htmlVal;
                   }
               });
           }
           function setEditStateValue(td1, indexRow) {
               for (var k in EditRowData) {
                   $($(td1).children('.' + k)[0]).html('<input value="' + EditRowData[k] + '" class="userinput"  style="width: 99% " />');
               }
           }
   ```
2. On pressing Enter after inputting anything, bind enter input (You can change it to maybe a save button as you like.

   ```
           $("#dtexample tbody").on('keyup', 'input.userinput', function (e) {
                   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                            updateRowData(this.parentNode.parentNode);
                   }
           });
   ```
3. Update function to make call to server with parameters.

   ```
           function updateRowData(currentCells) {
               var table = $("#dtexample").DataTable();
               var row = table.row(currentCells);
               rowid = currentCells.getAttribute('id');
               var UpdateRowData = [];
               $.each(ColumnData, function (index, element) {
                   if (element.Editable==true) {
                       UpdateRowData.push({
                           'pname': element.Name , 'pvalue': $($($(currentCells).children('.' + element.Name)).children('input')[0]).val()
                       });
                   }
               });
               console.log(UpdateRowData);
               UpdateRowData.push({ 'pname': 'rowid', 'pvalue': rowid });
               var parameter = "";
               for (i = 0; i < UpdateRowData.length; i++) {
                   if (i == UpdateRowData.length - 1)
                       parameter = parameter + UpdateRowData[i].pname + "=" + UpdateRowData[i].pvalue;
                   else
                       parameter = parameter + UpdateRowData[i].pname + "=" + UpdateRowData[i].pvalue + "&";
               }
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: '/WebService.asmx/UpdateTableData',
                   data: parameter,
                   success: function (data) {
                       var table = $('#dtexample').DataTable();
                       table.draw('page');
                   }
               });
           }
   ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22107115)

Comment: @juzraai Added the important parts of code and steps.

Comment: @shubham What are `indexv` and `rowIndex` attributes? They are usually undefined.

Comment: @user1742529 the indexv you can use in case at time of table data binding, you don't have a unique ID for row, so you can create a unique row ID yourself using some logic and add it to indexv attribute of each row.

Answer (score 3):

The editor license bit me in the butt, so I'm here to hopefully save yours.

Here's how I went about it:

1. When creating the table, add the class 'editable' to any element you'd like to edit

   ```
   example = new DataTable('#example', {
     columns: [
       { data: 'domain', name: 'domain' },
       { data: 'owner1', name: 'owner1', className: 'editable' },
       { data: 'owner2', name: 'owner2', className: 'editable'  },
       { data: 'description', name: 'description', className: 'editable' },
       { data: 'account_state', name: 'account-state' },
     ],
   });
   ```
2. Create mouse events for when you enter/exit a td. I chose to create an input element with mouse hover because I didn't want actual html inputs everywhere

   ```
   // when the mouse enters a cell, create an editor. 
   $('#example').on('mouseenter', 'td.editable', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault() // I'm a noob, don't know what this means
     // I think there is some delay on when the events trigger 
     // so sometimes the cell still contains the input element and this check
     // prevents accidently creating another input element
     if (e.target.localName != 'input') {
       let row = e.target._DT_CellIndex.row
       let col = e.target._DT_CellIndex.column
       if (!e.target.children.length) {
           e.target.innerHTML = `<input id="${row}-${col}" type="text" class="editor" value="${e.target.innerHTML}">`
       }
     }
   })

   // when the mouse exits the editor, write the data into the table and redraw
   $('#example').on('mouseleave', 'td.editable', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     if (e.target.localName != 'input') {
       let row = e.target._DT_CellIndex.row
       let col = e.target._DT_CellIndex.column
       data_table.cell(row, col).data(e.target.firstElementChild.value)
       data_table.draw() // up to you
     }
     else { // forces write when there is an event delay
       let [row, col] = e.target.id.split('-')
       data_table.cell(Number(row), Number(col)).data(e.target.value)
     }
     data_table.draw()
   })
   ```

That's it!

My table is at most about 2000 entries (definitely still usable), but I
'm sure there are performance improvements, and I'd love to know them!