# Implementation of edit and delete with DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need help.

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin and I need to implement edit and delete actions WITHOUT EDITOR PLUGIN.

I managed to render buttons. This is my table definition:

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        dom : 'Bfrtip',
        ajax : {
            url: '....'
        },
        sAjaxDataProp: "",
        columns: [
            {data : 'id'},
            {data : 'name'},
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'text-right',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a class="btn btn-danger" data-id="' + row[1] + '">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>' +
                        '</a>'
                    +
                        '<a class="btn btn-primary" data-id="' + row[1] + '">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span>' +
                        '</a>'
                }
            }
        ],
        order: [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        select: true
    });
```

But I don't know how (or where) to implement functionality that buttons represent. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

- when edit button is selected:

  - ALL values in the row become selectable/editable (i need to fetch selectable data from server)
  - column with edit and delete buttons rerenders with save and cancel buttons instead of edit and delete
- when delete button is selected:

  - a confirm dialog shows

I don't know where to write this code that triggers on click and how to fetch data from the server. Can someone please give some directions?
I'm really confused and I've been trying to find something useful but most of the questions/answers are not for beginners.

Thank You!

Comment: Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856961/datatable-inline-editing-without-editor-plugin/31859208#31859208

Comment: It's different from what I'm trying to achieve. I'm using action buttons, and honestly, I don't understand it enough to apply it on my situation, but thanks.

Comment: It's not overly different TBH. What have you tired so far?

Comment: You can see this http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/4toLj9yn/847/

Comment: Thank you, that's a good start. Do you maybe know how to render name cell differently depending on editing state? I want to show input element with name when edit button is selected, but only name otherwise. I would like to keep original data, only render it differently cause I need to be able to restore data on cancel.

Comment: You can use content-editable for the td element and add button cancel for return normal state http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/4toLj9yn/848/