# Inline editing datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

Hi I have been trying to follow this tutorial about inline editing http://www.vandelaydesign.com/inline-edit-with-ajax/ . I want to apply it in my data table. When the user clicks the edit button the corresponding columns within its line becomes an input, but I do not know how to turn it that way. In the tutorial it uses `.prev` in jquery to get the value of the of the `span` but I do not know how to do that in my case. This is what my table looks like:

[image]

**Category name and desc should become inputs when edit button is clicked. How do I do that?**

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <span id="<?= $category->category_id ?>" class="datainfo"> <?= $category->category_name ?>  </span> </td>
            <td>
                <?= $category->category_desc ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $category->created_on ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $category->updated_on ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $category->status ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="edit_cat" class="btn btn-light btn-sm edit_cat">
                    <!-- data-id="<?= $category->category_id ?>" -->
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit_cat', function() {
      console.log('edit category');
      // console.log( $(this).data('id') );
      var dataset = $(this).prev(".datainfo");
      console.log(dataset);
      var theid   = dataset.attr("id");
      console.log(theid);
      var newid   = theid+"-form";
      var currval = dataset.text();

      dataset.empty();

       $('<input type="text" name="'+newid+'" id="'+newid+'" value="'+currval+'" class="hlite">').appendTo(dataset);

    });
```

I also need help in future proofing after solving this problem, How would I go about saving it, maybe getting the span id and start from there?

Comment: the link you provided isnt of datatable

Comment: Datatables have a build in implementation of inline editing. Take look here -
 https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: @sintakonte you can post this as answer for my data table question.

Comment: alright thx - i made an answer ;)

Comment: I have done this inline functionality here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54505835/6862964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables have a build in implementation of inline editing.

It gets installed as an own extension

> Inline editing in Editor is activated through the use of the [inline()](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/api/inline()) API method. Simply call the method and pass in the cell you want to edit as the first parameter.
>
> Take a closer look here - https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple