# CodeIgniter - Click on cell to edit instead of edit button

Tags: database, codeigniter, datatables, edit

I am using CodeIgniter with DataTables. My employer wants to edit cells (column data) by double clicking them instead of having an Edit column. Is it possible to do this? I found a similar question where a JS function is called when the user clicks the row like `alert("you clicked row with ID ?")` but I need to go deeper and get the exact cell where I click, being able to double click it ( I know datatables doesnt differentiate normal click and double click) and edit it in place ( just like Excel). Currently I am using, I guess you would call the "standard" solution, the edit button takes me on a page with a form, where I retrieved current values to inputs and there you can edit it, submit sends the values to the Model which then updates the DB.

So is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: There is an example of DataTables inline editing [HERE](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datatable inline editing without editor plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856961/datatable-inline-editing-without-editor-plugin)